# Y-axis in MATLAB bar plot is hidden

Tags: matlab

I am drawing a simple bar diagram in MATLAB. The problem is, that the value
at x = 0 lets the y-axis disappear partially. Is there a way to bring the y-axis
to the front instead of hiding between the y-value for x=0? Is there any
option I can make sure the y-axis is always in the front?

Answer (score 10):

This here does the trick for anyone who faces the same problem in the future: set(gca,'layer','top')